# Typescript error when outputting key/value from mapped Object with Object.keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following Typescript error in a React application when attempting to map over an object of errors and display the key value, and the key as the anchor href.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"errors"' can't be used to index type '{ paid?: string | undefined; }'.
  Property 'errors' does not exist on type '{ paid?: string | undefined; }'.ts(7053)
```

Below is the Component

```
interface ErrorProps {
  errors: {
    paid?: string
  }
}

function Error(props: ErrorProps) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.errors && Object.keys(props.errors).map(key => {
        return (
          <li key={key}>
            <a href={`#${key}`}>
              {props.errors[key as keyof ErrorProps.errors]} // The error is on this line
            </a>
          </li> 
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

The following is the Props passed to the Errors Component:

```
errors: {paid: "Paid must be a number"}
```

What I am attempting to get in the resulting HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="#paid">Paid must be a number</a>
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorProps.errors` is a *type*, not a *namespace*. Consider changing the way how you retrieve the *nested* type.

```
{props.errors[key as keyof ErrorProps['errors']]}
```

Comment: Thanks kind, this still errors: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type '{ paid?: string | undefined; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ paid?: string | undefined; }'.ts(7053)

Comment: @LeMoi Its related with `strictFunctionTypes` option in ts, you could probably include this info in your question or either disable that option in your tsconfig. For me, that rule doesnt make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, your solution worked, thanks so much for your help!